# SAS:how to count average interval time

Tags: sas

how to count average interval time

```
+-------------+----------+----------+--------+------------------+
| customer_id |   date   |   time   | answer | missed_call_type |
+-------------+----------+----------+--------+------------------+
|         101 | 2018/8/3 | 12:13:00 | no     | employee         |
|         102 | 2018/8/3 | 12:15:00 | no     | customer         |
|         103 | 2018/8/3 | 12:20:00 | no     | employee         |
|         102 | 2018/8/3 | 15:15:00 | no     | customer         |
|         101 | 2018/8/3 | 18:15:00 | no     | employee         |
|         105 | 2018/8/3 | 18:18:00 | no     | customer         |
|         102 | 2018/8/3 | 19:18:00 | no     | employee         |
+-------------+----------+----------+--------+------------------+
```

I got a table which looks like this and wanted to calculate average interval time for those who did not answer the phone. For this example,the average interval time is:

> [(18:15:00-12:13:00)+(19:18:00-15:15:00)+(15:15:00-12:15:00)]/3

it could work in mssql, and could create a colum interval_time for each customer then sum up. How to achive it in sas？data step or proc sql

```
CREATE TABLE customer_data (
  customer_id BIGINT,
  date DATE, 
  time time, 
  answer VARCHAR(100), 
  missed_call_type VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO customer_data
VALUES
(101, '2018/8/3', '12:13:00', 'no', 'employee'),
(102, '2018/8/3', '12:15:00', 'no', 'customer'),
(103, '2018/8/3', '12:20:00', 'no', 'employee'),
(102, '2018/8/3', '15:15:00', 'no', 'customer'),
(101, '2018/8/3', '18:15:00', 'no', 'employee'),
(105, '2018/8/3', '18:18:00', 'no', 'customer'),
(102, '2018/8/3', '19:18:00', 'no', 'employee')

select cd.customer_id, answer, missed_call_type,
        CAST(CAST(cd.date as VARCHAR(10))+' ' +CAST(cd.time as VARCHAR(10)) as datetime) as date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cd.customer_id ORDER BY date desc, time desc) as ranks
INTO #temP
from customer_data cd
order by cd.customer_Id, ranks;

select AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x1.date, x2.date)) as avg_mins
from #temP x1
INNER JOIN #temP x2 ON x1.customer_id = x2.customer_id 
WHERE x2.ranks = (x1.ranks-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested query can be used to prepare the data for the selection and computation you want.  An important feature is to recognize that the datetime range (max-min) of a customer_id group is the same as adding up the sequential intervals of all the nos.

```
data have;
input customer_id date & yymmdd8. time & time8. answer $ missed_call_type $; 
format date yymmdd10. time time8.;
datetime = dhms(date,hour(time), minute(time), second(time));
format datetime datetime20.;
datalines;
101  2018/8/3  12:13:00  no      employee         
102  2018/8/3  12:15:00  no      customer         
103  2018/8/3  12:20:00  no      employee         
102  2018/8/3  15:15:00  no      customer         
101  2018/8/3  18:15:00  no      employee         
105  2018/8/3  18:18:00  no      customer         
102  2018/8/3  19:18:00  no      employee     
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select 
    sum(range) / sum (interval_count) as mean_interval_time format=time8.
  , sum(range) as sum_range format=time8.
  , sum(interval_count) as sum_interval_count
  , count(range) as group_count
  from
  ( select 
      max(datetime) - min(datetime) as range
    , count(*) - 1 as interval_count    
    from have
    group by customer_id
    having count(*) > 1
  );
```

You do not explain what should happen if the answer=yes, so the actual query may be more complicated than shown here.